# Logitech C922 1080 HD webcam unrecognized

Tags: webcam

My Logitech C922 Webcam worked fine on Juno but is unrecognized on Loki. Installing chees did not help, and Logitech's site offers no Linux drivers. Thought there might be an open source driver available somewhere, but googling around produced no useful info. Looking for advice on finding a driver or, failing that, advice on what HD webcam will be recognized by Loki.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Good folks at Elementary just posted an update to Camera. This Logitech model is now recognized by Elementary's Camera app and by Google Hangouts. Motion is actually rendered more smoothly in Hangouts.